# Split and subset from rows of a data.farme

Tags: r

how it is possible to extract patterns as NM_001291928 (one time) and Adora1 from this type of string using strsplit?

"gene_id ""NM_001291928""; transcript_id ""NM_001291928""; gene_name ""Adora1"";"

I tried:

> ```
>   strsplit(as.character(mydf[,1]), split=';', fixed=TRUE)
> ```

as a first attempt to at least split the lines and then subset what I need but without success.

I have a data.frame with 20.000 rows with the same structure of the line above but of course with a different content.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
str_remove_all(str1, '"') %>%
    str_extract_all("(?<=(gene_id|gene_name) )\\w+")
#[[1]]
#[1] "NM_001291928" "Adora1"
```

---

Or using `strsplit`

```
lapply(strsplit(gsub('"', '', str1), '[; ]+'), `[`, c(2, 6))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '"gene_id ""NM_001291928""; transcript_id ""NM_001291928""; gene_name ""Adora1"";"'
```

Comment: But I have a data.frame with 20.000 rows with the same structure.

Comment: @Elb  It wouldn't matter as you have to pass `str_remove_all(df1$yourcolumn,`

Comment: Yes you're right! It works perfectly! Thank you very much!